# Error percentage calculation in trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, error-propagation

I have question like that and i need to implement solution to python but i don't quite understand how it can doable can you help me?

If $f(x) = 5\tan(x) – 9x$, find the percentage error in $f(x)$ for $x=\frac{\pi}4$, if the error in $x$ is $0.003$.

Answer (score 0):

Error propagation is usually done assuming linearity, so $\Delta (f(x))\approx \frac {df(x)}{dx}\Delta (x)$.  You evaluate the derivative at the $x$ of interest.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance :)